# How do I move forward after working with a toxic academic supervisor?

Tags: graduate-school, postdocs, career-path, academic-life, early-career

How do I move forward after working with a toxic academic supervisor who ruined my all job opportunities by giving negative referrals, when my next job is asking referee report from him?

If anyone has gone through a similar experience and survived, would love to hear how you survived.

Comment: What sort of letter can you expect from him? What sort of letters has he written in the past?

Comment: Did any of his previous postdocs succeed? If so, can you find out what they did?

Comment: If he were really such a good story teller and such a good politician, he would write you a positive report even if he did not like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying, and you are asked to provide referrals, you can just skip this or name 1 instead of 3 etc. I have skipped this information and I was still invited to an interview even at King's college and Oxford, though I couldn't attend neither due to timing issues. Perhaps it would come up at later stages or say for lectureship but, the person I applied to said my resume looked impressive. This is such a toxic academic rule, do they ever ask the interviewee to evaluate their supervisors? No.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to be transparent about the relationship in the lab when potential employers ask for that reference. However, assuming you warned whatever graduate degree you had, it can also be taken as a sign that despite a toxic work environment you were able to still carve out success. Everyone has experienced a toxic work environment, so if your story is authentic, and you sound authentic, employers might be able to identify that.

But what you can’t do is use that supervisor as a reference, and you most likely won’t get other faculty to speak poorly about your supervisor in a letter. So, I would argue, that you just need to be transparent about your experience when you need to confront it.

Comment: You will need to address this upfront, but be cautious about assigning blame. A simple statement that you and your advisor don't have a positive personal relationship is probably enough. In addition, get a collaborator, colleague, someone on your defense committee, etc., to write you a positive LOR. It doesn't have to trash your advisor, just something that talks about you in a positive light.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for positions that do not require a reference.

You can use other people as a reference.